# Setting up an WordPress RSS feed - basics

Tags: wordpress, rss

Ok, so this is my first attempt at setting up an RSS feed.

Here is what my client wants.  He has a blog that he writes to about 3 times per week.

He wants me to set up the RSS feed so that when he posts to his Wordpress Blog, the RSS feed generates a feed with the title of the blog.

Where do i begin?

Im on an Apache server, and im farily adept at using PHP...but dont know the process to begin.

thanks

Comment: Doesn't Wordpress come with RSS support built-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has full, built-in RSS capabilities: [WordPress Feeds « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds). If you need more or different functionality, look at the feed plugins: [RSS WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=rss&sort=)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Wordpress' built-in Plugin search to search for an RSS plugin feed and go through each of their features. It should be as easy to just download and install the plugin. Some even comes with other configurations you can make and it automatically (usually) updates the Wordpress blog indicating to the bot where the RSS feed is (and even puts on a nice RSS feed image for you to use)

Hundreds out there, I suggest you start within Wordpress and read the user ratings on some of the plugins